# OpenCV dll calls from Unity3D lead to FPS drop

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, unity-game-engine, interop

I want to recognize ArUco Marker in Unity3D and attach a GameObject to their position. I know there are packages in the Asset Store, but as other people got it working I was looking for an free existing solution or try it by myself.

[ArucoUnity](https://github.com/NormandErwan/ArucoUnity) The detection worked like a charm, but Unity crashes when accessing the data of the `rvecs`, `tvecs`. The error somewhere occur in the `Get(int i)` in the `Vec3d` class, when the c++ method `au_cv_Vec3d_get(CppPtr, i, CppPtr);` is called

[OpenCv plus Unity](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-plus-unity-85928) This implementation seems not to be complete as there exist no function to `EstimatePoseSingleMarker` or similar to get the `rvecs` and `tvecs`. Also the last updated was Jan 2019.

As Unity (C#) provides the possibility to access unmanaged code, I followed [this](http://thomasmountainborn.com/2016/09/11/unity-and-opencv-part-one-install/) great tutorial and for the begging I was able to forward the `cv::VideoCaputre` stream to Unity. The only problem that occured was a FPS drop to around 35-40 whereas normally I get around 90-100.

The C# code:

```
void Update()
{
    MatToTexture2D();
    image.texture = tex;
}

void MatToTexture2D()
{
    OpenCVInterop.GetRawImageBytes(pixelPtr);
    //Update the Texture2D with array updated in C++
    tex.SetPixels32(pixel32);
    tex.Apply();
}
```

The C++ code:

```
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall  GetRawImageBytes(unsigned char* data)
{
    _capture >> _currentFrame;

    cv::Mat resizedMat(camHeight, camWidth, _currentFrame.type());
    cv::resize(_currentFrame, resizedMat, resizedMat.size(), cv::INTER_CUBIC);

    //Convert from RGB to ARGB 
    cv::Mat argb_img;
    cv::cvtColor(resizedMat, argb_img, cv::COLOR_BGR2BGRA);
    std::vector<cv::Mat> bgra;
    cv::split(argb_img, bgra);
    std::swap(bgra[0], bgra[3]);
    std::swap(bgra[1], bgra[2]);
    std::memcpy(data, argb_img.data, argb_img.total() * argb_img.elemSize());
}
```

The cause seems to be the first line `_capture >> _currentFrame;`, but as the others projects have to do the same (at least I guess so), I wonder if there is another reason.
If I don't manage to fix this issue I have to look for alternative approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding to / building on [Mars' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58925407/7111561):

For the threading problem I would actually use a thread-save [`ConcurrentStack<Color32[]>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1). A stack is "last-in | first-out" so that the first item returned is always the last image data added by the thread.

- The thread uses `Push(pixel32)` to add a new entry with image data
- in `Update` you only use the latest entry (`TryPop`) for updating the texture.
- The rest you ignore (`Clear`).

So something like

```
// the OpenCV thread will add(push) entries
// the Unity main thread will work on the entries
private ConcurrentStack<Color32[]> stack = new ConcurrentStack<Color32[]>();

public RawImage image;
public Texture2D tex;

private Thread thread;

void Start()
{
    // Wherever you get your tex from
    tex = new Texture2D(...);

    // it should be enough to do this only once
    // the texture stays the same, you only update its content
    image.texture = tex;
}

// do things in OnEnable so everytime the object gets enabled start the thread
void OnEnable()
{
    stack.Clear();

    if(thread != null)
    {
        thread.Abort();
    }

    thread = new Thread(MatToTexture2D);
    thread.Start();
}

void Update()
{
    // here in the main thread work the stack
    if (stack.TryPop(out var pixels32))
    {
        // Only use SetPixels and Apply when really needed
        tex.SetPixels32(pixels32);
        tex.Apply();
    }

    // Erase older data
    stack.Clear();
}

// Make sure to terminate the thread everytime this object gets disabled
private void OnDisable()
{
    if(thread == null) return;

    thread.Abort();
    thread = null;
}

// Runs in a thread!
void MatToTexture2D()
{
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do what you already have
            OpenCVInterop.GetRawImageBytes(pixelPtr);

            // However you convert the pixelPtr into Color32
            Color32[] pixel32 = GetColorArrayFromPtr(pixelPtr);

            // Now add this data to the stack
            stack.Push(pixel32);
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException ex) 
        { 
            // This exception is thrown when calling Abort on the thread
            // -> ignore the exception since it is produced on purpose
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack is a great answer if you're sure it won't pop your memory! And not re-setting the data when there's no new image is a solid improvement too.

Comment: But for what it's worth, I think if there is ever the rare case that the stack contains more than one image, you probably want to run through all of the images (essentially 2-3x playback speed until you're caught up)

Comment: For a similar production project, the spec was a *heap* (FIFO), with a max size :)

Comment: @Mars Not sure, for the rare case that OpenCV manages to capture two images within one frame I guess I throw the second away ^^ But sure maybe there are other options. Would require some decisions, maths and simply testing to find out the "perfect" solution here.

Comment: As the OpenCV thread would run as a separate thread, I think it would be immune to things like `GameObject.enabled = false`, meaning the stack would keep pumping, but update wouldn't run. I haven't touched Unity in years, so not sure if that's the exact case, but I recall there is some way to make the gameobject cycle stop running

Comment: Sure .. you're right I guess, thanks for the hint! Just updated it using `OnEnable` to start a thread and `OnDisable` to terminate it

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the C++ call to get an image (`_capture >> _currentFrame;`) is blocking/synchronous, meaning your code won't continue until it actually retrieves the image. You probably want to run your `MatToTexture2D` code asynchronously.
※This will mean that your frame rate will be higher than your image retrieval rate.

Have your `MatToTexture2D` function run continuously as needed, updating `tex`. Then just continue to set your texture to the latest `tex`, which may be the same value 2-3 frames in a row.

---

Edit: 
[@derHugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58928548/3838167) is much more solid for the programming side, so I'll hide that part. The basic issue is explained above, and derHugo's work-around is much better than my pseudo-code :)